# How to get the maximum item ordered by two fields using a Linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to get result1 as a single linq expression? I understand that it may not be the best practise but I would just like to know how to do so out of curiousity.

result2 has a different answer but it correct too. However, it has a complexity of O(NlogN) as opposed to O(N).

```
void Main()
{
    A[] a = new A[4]{new A(0,0,0),new A(1,1,0),new A(1,2,1),new A(1,2,0)};
    /*
    //Grossly inefficient: replaced
    var tmpList = a.Where(x => (x.one == a.Max(y => y.one)));       
    var result1 = tmpList.First(x => (x.two == tmpList.Max(y => y.two)));
    */
    var maxOneValue = a.Max(x => x.one);
    var tmpList = a.Where(x => (x.one == maxOneValue));
    var maxTwoValueOfTmpList = tmpList.Max(x => x.two);
    var result1 = tmpList.First(x => (x.two == maxTwoValueOfTmpList));
    //A: 1, 2, 1

    var result2 = a.OrderBy(x => x.one)
              .ThenBy(x => x.two)
              .Last();
    //A: 1, 2, 0
}

class A 
{
    public int one;
    public int two;
    public int three;
    public A(int one, int two, int three)
    {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
        this.three = three;
    }
}
```

edit: I have edited by question and hence some answers may not tally.

Comment: Is ordering on the sum of both fields what you want? Or effectively on their average?

Comment: I want to get a single 'A' with the maximum 'two' value from a list of 'A's with the maximum 'one' value from an initial list of 'A's.

Comment: @Johannes Rudolph: Nope, I don't want an ordering on the sum or average of two fields. While I can get a result by performing a sort based on 'one', followed by a sort based on 'two' within each range of values with the same 'one' value, I do not necessarily need to sort twice to get a valid result. Sorry for not answering your question directly previously as I didn't understand what you meant until I saw Jani's answer.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this solves your problem:

```
a.OrderBy(x => x.one + x.two).Last()
```

Comment: Or `OrderByDescending` and `First`, which I think might save you a linear sweep through the enumerable.

Comment: "Nope, I don't want an ordering on the sum or average of two fields"

Answer (score 1):

This query gives the same result :

```
var result = a.OrderByDescending(x => x.one + x.two)
                      .First();
```

But then you could get items without max 'one' field..
This one should work :

```
var result = a.OrderByDescending(x => x.two)
               .Where(x => (x.one == a.Max(y => y.one)))
               .First();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to implement `IComparable<A>` on your `A` class. Then your solution simply becomes:

```
var result1 = a.Max(); // 1,2,1
```

Here's how you would implement `IComparable<A>`:

```
class A : IComparable<A>
{
    ...

    public int CompareTo(A other)
    {

        return this.one == other.one ? this.two - other.two : this.one - other.one;
    }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://ideone.com/ufIcgf. The nice thing about this is that it still has a complexity of `O(N)`, and is also fairly concise.

Comment: ... I took about 10 lines of code to do what you did in one. Nice work.

Comment: @Rawling Heh, well thanks for walking me through what I was doing wrong in the first place.